# Create columns for the values of the first n weeks for each product code

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame like this:

```
> df1 <- data.frame(product_code=c(201,201,201,201,201,201,301,301,301,301,301),
+                  week=c(3,4,5,6,7,8,5,6,7,8,9),
+                  first_week=c(3,3,3,3,3,3,5,5,5,5,5),
+                  sales=c(12,14,13,15,17,18,34,41,38,43,47))
> df1
   product_code week first_week sales
1           201    3          3    12
2           201    4          3    14
3           201    5          3    13
4           201    6          3    15
5           201    7          3    17
6           201    8          3    18
7           301    5          5    34
8           301    6          5    41
9           301    7          5    38
10          301    8          5    43
11          301    9          5    47
```

I would like to transform the data frame so that there is a column with sales for the first 4 weeks of each product in the data frame. The first week of each product is given in the data frame.

The output should look like this:

```
> df2 <- data.frame(product_code=c(201,301),
+                   first_week=c(12,34),
+                   second_week=c(14,41),
+                   third_week=c(13,38),
+                   fourth_week=c(15,43))
> df2
  product_code first_week second_week third_week fourth_week
1          201         12          14         13          15
2          301         34          41         38          43
```

In total I would like to do that for the first 52 weeks of each product.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `tidyr::pivot_wider`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df1 %>% 
  group_by(product_code) %>%
  mutate(n = row_number()) %>% 
  pivot_wider(product_code, names_from = n, names_prefix = "week", values_from = sales)

# A tibble: 2 x 7
# Groups:   product_code [2]
  product_code week1 week2 week3 week4 week5 week6
         <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1          201    12    14    13    15    17    18
2          301    34    41    38    43    47    NA
```

To exactly match your expected output, you can use `english::ordinal`:

```r
df1 %>% 
  group_by(product_code) %>%
  mutate(n = english::ordinal(row_number())) %>% 
  pivot_wider(product_code, names_from = n, names_glue = "{n}_week", values_from = sales)

  product_code first_week second_week third_week fourth_week fifth_week sixth_week
         <dbl>      <dbl>       <dbl>      <dbl>       <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>
1          201         12          14         13          15         17         18
2          301         34          41         38          43         47         NA
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I have installed tidyverse but get an error message when I run the code ('mutate' is not found). Do you have any advice?

Comment: Don't forget to add `library(tidyverse)`

Comment: I found the mistake, I forgot ```library(dplyr)``` :)
So the code works well now, thanks! But how can I set a maximum of columns? For example only the first 4 weeks in this case (or the first 52 weeks in my actual data frame)? Your code automatically provides the maximum number of weeks that are available in the data frame (so 6 in this case).

Comment: You can filter first, e.g. add `filter(row_number() <= 4)` before pivoting